# PHP missing argument but it isn't missed, it only happens on production

Tags: php, json, digital-ocean

i've been writing a inside tool for my company and i tested it and everything was working correctly, but when it happens to be on the server, it rejects the connection for missing arguments, it's not completely weird because i coded that behavior, but when i was testing it in localhost, it didn't behave like that, we're currently deploying tools on digital ocean and i the tool receive the data in JSON format

```
    include("./request.php");
    include("./urlParams.php");
    include("./conexion.php");

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    error_reporting(0);
    main($conexion);

    function main($conexion){
        //$values = getParams(array( 'webinarHash', 'fecha'));
        

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        
        if( !( isset($data['webinarHash']) && isset($data['fecha']) ) ){
            $response = array('message' => 'Rechazado, argumento faltante');
            http_response_code(400);
            echo json_encode($response);
            die();
        }

        $webinarHash = $data['webinarHash'];
        $date        = $data['fecha'];
```

what could be the reason for the rejection??

Comment: _Missing argument_ you say?

Comment: yes, missing argument

Comment: I recommend some more precise debugging on the server, to figure out what exactly is in `php://input`. Is the input stream empty (my guess)? Is it not valid JSON? Or does it only have `webinarHash`, and not `fecha`?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to tell without more context.

The `$conexion` is missing. Make sure it is defined before you execute `main($conexion);`
It's probably defined in one of the 3 included php files at the top. Maybe the code in there does not initialized the variable correctly because the logic behaves different on your prod system than on localhost.

If the given code snippets represents the full `main` function you could also drop the `$conexion` variable completely.

Comment: the $conexion is my db connection, i used it to post on my db, but, the params when i make the request is the main issue, the code here sends the missing argument response when one or the two arguments in my json is missing, but on postman when i send the json it returns the message, when it shouldn't behave like that

Answer (score 0):

NVM Guys i have found the issue, it is our server configuration